# Numpy: Row Wise Unique elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Does any one know how to get unique elements row wise in a matrix. For e.g. input matrix may be like:

```
a = [[1,2,1,3,4,1,3],
     [5,5,3,1,5,1,2],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
     [9,3,8,2,9,8,4],
     [4,6,7,4,2,3,5]]
```

It should return the following:

```
b = rowWiseUnique(a)
=>  b = [[1,2,3,4,0,0,0],
       [5,3,1,2,0,0,0],
       [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
       [9,3,8,2,4,0,0],
       [4,6,7,2,3,5,0]]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this in numpy? I tried the following code, is there a better and shorter way of doing this?

```
import numpy as np
def uniqueRowElements(row):
    length = row.shape[0]
    newRow = np.unique(row)
    zerosNumb = length-newRow.shape[0]
    zeros = np.zeros(zerosNumb)
    nR = np.concatenate((newRow,zeros),axis=0)
    return nR    

b = map(uniqueRowElements,a)
b = np.asarray(b)
print b
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicates and replace them with zero?  What have you tried so far, and why is it deficient?

Comment: Yes, what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a maximum value of the elements in `a`?

Comment: There is no limitation on value of elements

Comment: What is this for? The 0-padding at the end seems unnatural, even if it is aiming at preserving array structure.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why is this unnatural to have zero padding in the end?

Comment: Do you need to retain the order of the unique elements?

Comment: No order is not important, only uniqueness is important

Comment: Have you tried ```numpy.unique```?

Comment: If you didn't need to preserve structure than I imagine `map(np.unique, a)` would be easy enough...

Comment: map(np.unique,a) returns a list of arrays but not a matrix as I want

Comment: Write a function ```foo```, using ```numpy.unique```, that accepts a 1-d array (a row) and returns your desired row.  Then use ```numpy.array(map(foo, a))```.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the values in `a` are floats, you could use:

```
def using_complex(a):
    weight = 1j*np.linspace(0, a.shape[1], a.shape[0], endpoint=False)
    b = a + weight[:, np.newaxis]
    u, ind = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    np.put(b, ind, a.flat[ind])
    return b

In [46]: using_complex(a)
Out[46]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [9, 3, 8, 2, 0, 0, 4],
       [4, 6, 7, 0, 2, 3, 5]])
```

Note that `using_complex` does not return the unique values in the same order as `rowWiseUnique`; per the comments underneath the question, sorting the values is not required.

---

The most efficient method may depend on the number of rows in the array.
Methods that use `map` or a `for-loop` to handle each row separately are good if the number of rows is not too large, 
but if there are lots of rows, you can do better by using a numpy trick to handle the entire array with one call to np.unique.

The trick is to add a unique imaginary number to each row. 
That way, when you call `np.unique`, the floats in the original array will be
recognized as different values if they occur in different rows, but be treated
as the same value if they occur in the same row.

Below, this trick is implemented in the function `using_complex`. Here is a benchmark comparing `rowWiseUnique`, the original method, with `using_complex` and `solve`:

```
In [87]: arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(100000, 10))

In [88]: %timeit rowWiseUnique(arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.34 s per loop

In [89]: %timeit solve(arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.78 s per loop

In [90]: %timeit using_complex(arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 206 ms per loop
```

---

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,1,3,4,1,3],
     [5,5,3,1,5,1,2],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
     [9,3,8,2,9,8,4],
     [4,6,7,4,2,3,5]])

def using_complex(a):
    weight = 1j*np.linspace(0, a.shape[1], a.shape[0], endpoint=False)
    b = a + weight[:, np.newaxis]
    u, ind = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    np.put(b, ind, a.flat[ind])
    return b

def rowWiseUnique(a):
    b = map(uniqueRowElements,a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    return b

def uniqueRowElements(row):
    length = row.shape[0]
    newRow = np.unique(row)
    zerosNumb = length-newRow.shape[0]
    zeros = np.zeros(zerosNumb)
    nR = np.concatenate((newRow,zeros),axis=0)
    return nR    

def solve(arr):
    n = arr.shape[1]
    new_arr = np.empty(arr.shape)
    for i, row in enumerate(arr):
        new_row = np.unique(row)
        new_arr[i] = np.hstack((new_row, np.zeros(n - len(new_row))))
    return new_arr
```

Comment: Interesting, seems optimized for smaller lengths in the second axis - from timings anyway.  I'm going to have to noodle on this one.

Comment: @unutbu: Would it be also possible to generate an array of counts in the same shape as `a` with 0's in the positions where values were duplicated?

Comment: Off-hand, I don't know. Above, I tried to reduce the problem to *one call* to np.unique by differentiating the rows with complex numbers. I'm not sure what the analogous trick would be for your problem. I'm not entirely clear about the details of your problem either -- if there are 0's where the values are duplicated, where are the counts? Would the other positions all be 1's?

Comment: By the way, since the goal of this website is to build a searchable archive of good questions matched with good answers, it goes against this purpose to ask new questions in the comments. Please post a new question. I'd be happy to look at it, but I might not have an answer.

Comment: I was looking at `np.unique` documentation and in ver 1.9 there is an additional argument `return_counts` that returns the counts of each unique value. So just for the first row in the example `[1,2,1,3,4,1,3]` I would like something like this: [3,1,0,2,1,0,0]. But I can't figure out how to reconstruct a 2D array from the flat array that is returned...

Comment: Got it - please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789014/count-unique-elements-row-wise-in-an-ndarray

Comment: Note that the proposed solution is in a worse runtime class than the OPs initial solution. Since np.unique uses sorting, I assume it runs in O(n * log(n)). It follows that the proposed solution runs in O(n * m  * log(n * m)). The solutoin of the OP runs in O(n * m * log(m)), however. Here i suppose the original array has shape (n, m). Therefore, a solution using map might be better for large matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way should be to set all duplicates to zero using sort and diff:

```
def row_unique(a):
    unique = np.sort(a)
    duplicates = unique[:,  1:] == unique[:, :-1]
    unique[:, 1:][duplicates] = 0
    return unique
```

This is about 3 times as fast as the unutbu's solution on my computer:

```
In [26]: a = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=100000).reshape(1000, 100)

In [27]: %timeit row_unique(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit using_complex(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.4 ms per loop

In [29]: assert np.all(np.sort(using_complex(a)) == np.sort(row_unique(a)))
```

In order to return the counts of each unique element, one could also do:

```
def row_unique(a, return_counts=False):
    unique = np.sort(a)
    duplicates = unique[:,  1:] == unique[:, :-1]
    unique[:, 1:][duplicates] = 0
    if not return_counts:
        return unique
    count_matrix = np.zeros(a.size, dtype="int")
    idxs = np.flatnonzero(unique)
    counts = np.diff(idxs)
    count_matrix[idxs[:-1]] = counts
    count_matrix[idxs[-1]] = a.size-idxs[-1]
    return unique, count_matrix.reshape(a.shape)
```

`

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this particular solution has helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: This is really fast. Is there a way to also return the count for each unique element?

Comment: @JQK Added return_counts now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def solve(arr):
    n = arr.shape[1]
    new_arr = np.empty(arr.shape)
    for i, row in enumerate(arr):
        new_row = np.unique(row)
        new_arr[i] = np.hstack((new_row, np.zeros(n - len(new_row))))
    return new_arr
```

This is around 4X times faster than OP's current code for 1000 X 1000 array:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)
>>> %timeit b = map(uniqueRowElements, arr); b = np.asarray(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 71.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit solve(arr)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashwini. If I am not wrong, your code is gaining by preallocating the output array and in my code lot of time is spent in adjusting the output array size?

Comment: @Lanc Yes, exactly. `np.empty` is taking around only 400 ns for me. In your code the conversion of `b` to NumPy array is the slower part, `map(uniqueRowElements, arr)` takes around 14 ms on my system, rest of it is taken by `np.asarray`.

Comment: Try ```np.apply_along_axis(uniqueRowElements, 1, a)```.

Comment: @wwii That took around 19.5 ms.

Comment: I can't reproduce the speed gain, I have 96.3 ms for OP's 86.2 ms for yours.

Comment: @sebix I get timing (ratios) similar to @Ashwini with ```timeit.Timer```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on OP's solution with a slight improvement, ~3% when using `numpy.apply_along_axis` with large (1000x1000) arrays - but still a bit slower than @Ashwini's solution.

```
def foo(row):
    b = np.zeros(row.shape)
    u = np.unique(row)
    b[:u.shape[0]] = u
    return b

b = np.apply_along_axis(foo, 1, a)
```

Timing ratios seem to be a bit closer using an array with duplicates in the rows, `a = np.random.random_integers(0, 500, (1000*1000)).reshape(1000,1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very efficient, because moving all zeros into a row's end can't be very efficient.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,1,3,4,1,3],
     [5,5,3,1,5,1,2],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
     [9,3,8,2,9,8,4],
     [4,6,7,4,2,3,5]])

row_len = len(a[0])

for r in xrange(len(a)):
    found = set()
    for i in xrange(row_len):
        if a[r][i] not in found:
            found.add(a[r][i])
        else:
            a[r][i] = 0
    a[r].sort()
    a[r] = a[r][::-1]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[4 3 2 1 0 0 0]
 [5 3 2 1 0 0 0]
 [7 6 5 4 3 2 1]
 [9 8 4 3 2 0 0]
 [7 6 5 4 3 2 0]]
```

Comment: Using for loops is not recommended, if I have a huge matrix the above code is going to be very slow. I tried something in code above, have a look and please suggest if there is some better way of doing this.

Comment: @Lanc both numpy.unique and map() use 'for'. I don't think there is a way to accomplish your task without 'for'.