# How to record the "least occuring" item in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame, with only three columns:

```
import pandas pd
dict_example = {'col1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
    'col2':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 'col3':['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_example)

print(df)
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    A    A
1    A    B    A
2    A    A    A
3    A    B    C
4    A    A    B
```

For the rows with differing elements, I'm trying to write a function which will return the column names of the "minority" elements.

As an example, in row 1, there are 2 A's and 1 B. Given there is only one B, I consider this the "minority". If all elements are the same, there's naturally no minority (or majority). However, if each column has a different value, I consider these columns to be minorities.

Here is what I have in mind:

```
  col1 col2 col3   min
0    A    A    A   []
1    A    B    A   ['col2']
2    A    A    A   []
3    A    B    C   ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
4    A    A    B   ['col3']
```

I'm stumped how to computationally efficiently calculate this.

Finding the maximum number of items appears straightfoward, either with using `pandas.DataFrame.mode()` or one could find the maximum item in a list as follows:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'A']
max(lst,key=lst.count)
```

But I'm not sure how I could find either the least occurring items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not simple - but I could not think of a `pandas` native solution without `apply`, and `numpy` does not seemingly provide much help without the below complex  number trick for inner-row uniqueness and value counts.

---

If you are not fixed on adding this `min` column, we can use some `numpy` tricks to `nan` out the non-least-occuring entries. First, given your dataframe we can make a numpy array of integers to help.

<strike>`v = pd.factorize(df.stack())[0].reshape(df.shape)`</strike>

```
v = pd.factorize(df.values.flatten())[0].reshape(df.shape)
```

(should be faster, as stack is unecessary)

Then, using some tricks for numpy row-wise `unique` elements (using complex numbers to mark elements as unique in each row, find the least occurring elements, and *`mask` them in*). This method is mostly from user [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) used in several [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958233/numpy-row-wise-unique-elements/26960198#26960198).

```
def make_mask(a):
    weight = 1j*np.linspace(0, a.shape[1], a.shape[0], endpoint=False)
    b = a + weight[:, np.newaxis]
    u, ind, c = np.unique(b, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
    b = np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=float)
    np.put(b, ind, c)
    m = np.nanmin(b, axis=1)
    # remove only uniques
    b[(~np.isnan(b)).sum(axis=1) == 1, :] = np.nan
    # remove lower uniques
    b[~(b == m.reshape(-1, 1))] = np.nan
    return b

m = np.isnan(make_mask(v))
df[m] = np.nan
```

Giving

```
  col1 col2 col3
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    B  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    A    B    C
4  NaN  NaN    B
```

---

Hopefully this achieves what you want in a performant way (say if this dataframe is quite large). If there is a faster way to achieve the first line (without using `stack`), I would imagine this is quite fast for even very large dataframes.

Comment: Thanks! It is a large dataframe, so this operation should be performant. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I've found a situation whereby it's not working as expected. I have a row with 4 A and 2 B, and it's shows me that there are no "minority" characters. I could share the data with you perhaps?

Comment: yeah @EB2127 I can take a look

Comment: I'm not sure how to share the dataframe. The row is A, A, C, C, A, A